# Oracle partition-wise join over multiple partitions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm looking into partition-wise joins.

We are partitioning by a group of ids identified by a partition id.
For example

```
Partition Id         Element Id
1                    78
1                    55
1                    91
2                    12
2                    98
```

We are then partitioning based upon the partition id.

We are looking at ways to populate this table, a niiave approach is to insert the element's into this table based on our criteria.

However in some cases one element id may belong to two groups.

In the above case the element would only be inserted once. We would insert it first then on the second match we would check if that element has not already been added to the table. If it has it would not be added.

My question is if this happens and a partition-wise join happens then I believe the result set will be incomplete due to the element not residing in the correct partition.

Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean "one element id may belong to two groups"?  Your data doesn't seem to have any examples and the explanation is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: Group 1 elements will be inserted. Then Group 2 elements. If a group 2 element already exists in group 1 it will not be added

Comment: you have 2 entities E1 = (1, 'a'), E2 =(2, 'a'). you insert E1 into table. then when you try insert E2 and see that 'a' is already there. You skip it. Now you trying to select from a table and get both entities, correct? It is not possible.