# Partition wise join

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I have some doubt about "partition wise join", that includes Oracle:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9BMyQun84Y

[Oracle partition-wise join over multiple partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539703/oracle-partition-wise-join-over-multiple-partitions)

I don't understand this functionality. I have watched videos and I still doesn't understand  how to use it.

I understand partitioning but I doesn't understand this. I need a simple example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/vldbg/partition-wise-joins.html#GUID-7C28CD29-5189-4A53-9691-380E13515015), there's a good detailed and lengthy explanation.